# Roman numeral kata in Elixir

Tags: beginner, roman-numerals, elixir

I'm new to Elixir, and in order to learn the syntax, I'm doing a roman numeral kata which converts a decimal number into roman numeral. I would appreciate any feedback you have.

```
defmodule RomanNumeral do

  @decimal_roman_numerals [[5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'], [1, 'I']]

  def converts(number) do
    converts(number, [], @decimal_roman_numerals)
  end

  def converts(number, roman_value, _) when number < 1 do
    roman_value
  end

  def converts(number, roman_value, [[decimal, roman] | numerals]) when number >= decimal do
    converts(number - decimal, roman_value ++ roman, [[decimal, roman] | numerals])
  end

  def converts(number, roman_value, [_ | numerals]) do
    converts(number, roman_value, numerals)
  end
end
```

Comment: That is a very Prolog solution, which is good because Erlang is prolog inspired.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code looks very nice indeed, I only have some minor observations you code use to improve this code:

**Naming**
Use the imperative form of the verb (`convert` instead of `converts`)

**Implementation Hiding**
Use `defp` for methods which are not intended for external use. You might consider also renaming them to start with underscore `_` to further differentiate them as internal.

**Multiple assignment in method signature**
To make you code more succinct, you can use multiple assignment - meaning that instead of:

```
def converts(number, roman_value, [[decimal, roman] | numerals]) when number >= decimal do
  converts(number - decimal, roman_value ++ roman, [[decimal, roman] | numerals])
end
```

you can write:

```
def converts(number, roman_value, [[decimal, roman] | _] = numerals) 
  when number >= decimal do
  converts(number - decimal, roman_value ++ roman, numerals)
end
```

to the same effect. This form assigns the first item in the list to `[decimal, roman]`, as well as assigning the *whole* list (including the first element) to `numerals`, so you don't have to re-build it inside the method body.

---

Implementing the above suggestions, your code will look like this:

```
defmodule RomanNumeral do

  @decimal_roman_numerals [[5, 'V'], [4, 'IV'], [1, 'I']]

  def convert(number) do
    _convert(number, [], @decimal_roman_numerals)
  end

  defp _convert(number, roman_value, _) when number < 1 do
    roman_value
  end

  defp _convert(number, roman_value, [[decimal, roman] | _] = numerals) 
    when number >= decimal do
    _convert(number - decimal, roman_value ++ roman, numerals)
  end

  defp _convert(number, roman_value, [_ | numerals]) do
    _convert(number, roman_value, numerals)
  end
end
```